# I-Beam insertion curson goes missing occasionally

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, error

I bought this new Macbook Air, and am completely new to Mac OSX. 
I have Mac Sierra installed, and lately have noticed that the The I-Beam insertion cursor for the keyboard goes invisible occasionally. Maybe there's a shortcut or a trackpad problem, I'm not sure. Thought I could ask here.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard macOS behaviour.

The I-Beam cursor ought to go invisible as you start to type & only reappear if you stop typing & move the cursor.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that! Is there any way to change this setting for the keyboard? I was able to change the scrolling to normal windows-style scrolling with the scroll wheel via the mouse settings. Don't know how to get the cursor to normal. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not aware of there being any way to change this behaviour - for me it feels very sensible, saves having to keep moving the mouse out of the way when you're typing ;) Re: the 'natural scroll' though - yup, I'm right on your side with that one. It was introduced so that new users who were used to iPhones would feel the same scroll action on a trackpad. To an old mouse user like me, that's totally alien ;)

Comment: ok. Maybe I'll get used to the disappearing cursor. Also, the trackpad has a scroll gesture? Didn't know that! Will have to look at some tutorial online for that.. Thanks!